# angular mat-calendar adds a period after day date for i18n locale

Tags: angular, datepicker, internationalization

`<mat-calendar>` without a locale specified:

[image: without a locale specified]

and with a locale specified in `app-module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'nb'}
  ],
```

adds a period after the numerical day-date, pushing the numbers off center:

[image: dates have a period]

How can I format without the period? *Preferably* without looping through an array etc every time the user opens the view and calendar gets redrawn.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com and add the link to your question.

Comment: @Igor, no. This is so straight forward I am not going to spend time on that. It is literally 1 and a 1/2 lines of code and nothing else. Creating a mini-project will not help in any way. Sorry about that, but there is nothing more to add. I have a `<mat-calendar></mat-calendar>` tag, and the above mentioned line the providers section of app.module.ts. That's all there is.